# Forward email using ruby mail

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems

I am using ruby mail gem(https://github.com/mikel/mail) to forward messages from one mailbox to another.

Does anyone know how can I create a forward message?

There is a method in Tmail gem create_forward() on a mail to create a forwarded version of a given mail by setting the correct subject etc. I am looking for a similar method if available.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply save the mail sender and text as variables, create a new message to compose and use that info to construct a fwd: version?

Comment: Yes I can do that. But I also want the body to have text prepended which says who the original sender was and the original recipients etc. which is a little more than just changing the sender mail id and text. So I am seeing if there is a function available to do it.